# Google Cloud Function crashes with TypeError: 'Request' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have deployed a Google Cloud Function and am accessing it with an http GET request, with URL query string parameters.

However, it fails with an "Error: could not handle the request".

The function works perfectly fine, when I run it from a Colab notebook though.

I'm sharing the function code(main.py), requirements.txt and error log below:

main.py:

```
from goose3 import Goose
import validators
import json
from transformers import pipeline

def respond(err, res=None):
    print(err)
    print(res)
    return {
        'statusCode': '400' if err else '200',
        'body': err['message'] if err else json.dumps(res),
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    }

def extract_html(url):

    extractor = Goose({'browser_user_agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_2)','strict': False})
    article = extractor.extract(url=url)
    text = article.cleaned_text
    info = article.infos
    print("Extracted {} words.".format( str(len(text.split(' '))) ))

    return info, text

def t5(event):

    qs = event['queryStringParameters']
    if qs and 'url' in qs:
        url = qs['url']
        print(url)

        try:
            validators.url(url)
            info, text = extract_html(url)
            nlp_t5 = pipeline('summarization', model="t5-small", tokenizer="t5-small")
            summary = nlp_t5(text)
            data = {'url': url,
                    'info': info,
                    'meta_description': summary
                    }
            return respond(None, data)

        except ValidationFailure as e:
            err = {'message': 'Not a valid URL.'}
            return respond(err)

        except Exception as e:
            err = {'message': str(e)}
            return respond(err)

    else:
        return respond(ValueError('Missing parameter `url`.'))
```

requirements.txt:

```
https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.0.1.post2-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
transformers==2.7.0
validators==0.14.3
goose3==3.1.6
```

Error log:

```
{
 insertId: "xxxx-cea02c1b8e9a"  
 labels: {
  execution_id: "oq7e8d7dryic"   
 }
 logName: "xxxxxxx/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2020-04-15T11:21:52.415338305Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   function_name: "t5"    
   project_id: "xxxx"    
   region: "us-central1"    
  }
  type: "cloud_function"   
 }
 severity: "ERROR"  
 textPayload: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 346, in run_http_function
    result = _function_handler.invoke_user_function(flask.request)
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 217, in invoke_user_function
    return call_user_function(request_or_event)
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 210, in call_user_function
    return self._user_function(request_or_event)
  File "/user_code/main.py", line 30, in t5
    qs = event['queryStringParameters']
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 377, in <lambda>
    __getitem__ = lambda x, i: x._get_current_object()[i]
TypeError: 'Request' object is not subscriptable
"  
 timestamp: "2020-04-15T11:21:51.928Z"  
 trace: "xxxxxxx/traces/ac5c24180c1fce71fdcf32e39d88d1ff"  
}
```

Sample Triggering Event:

```
{
  "httpMethod": "GET",
  "queryStringParameters": {
    "url": "https://www.webmd.com/rx/physicians/"
  }
}
```

I have looked around for solutions to this but haven't been able to find any.

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Just curious: what made you think you could use `event['queryStringParameters']` here? Was that example used in some GCP documentation somewhere?

Comment: I have been using AWS lambda functions until now and made the incorrect assumption (probably a beginner mistake, apologies for this!) that the same request object would work on Google Cloud Functions too. Didn't realise that the request object here is a Flask object. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing:

```py
def t5(event):
    qs = event['queryStringParameters']
    if qs and 'url' in qs:
        url = qs['url']
        ...
```

but the object passed to the function here is a [Flask request object](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http), so you need to do:

```py
def t5(event):
    url = event.args.get("url")
    if url:
        ...
```

I'd recommend renaming the parameter so it's not confused with a [background function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background):

```
def t5(request):
    url = request.args.get("url")
    if url:
        ...
```

You'll also want to update your `respond` method to return a string, tuple, or `Response` instance. Something like:

```py
def respond(err, res=None):
    print(err)
    print(res)

    if err:
        return err['message'], 400, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    else:
        return json.dumps(res), 200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, Dustin. I implemented the above and have now got the below error:
`TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a dict.`
Have I gone wrong with the response object as well? 
Apologies, I am a beginner with Google Cloud Functions. Have been using AWS lambda functions until now and I'm just switching over.